# Power bi embedded report, getting 403 errors on all images

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I've embedded a report on a web app(javascript app owns data), the report works fine and i'm able to apply filters etc, but i'm getting 403 forbidden errors on all the images used by the report. I have no issues with the images when viewed directly on the power bi service, this is specific to embedded reports. I even created a new app(new clientId), and gave it more permissions, but that didn't help. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[403 forbidden errors when loading images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjxiC.png)

Comment: I have the same issue here, for me the problem occurs when I clone a report and the embed token of the clone doesn't have privilege to access the images from the original report, when I use the original report token I can get the images successfully. I tested through fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with object restrictions and\or permissions.

Make sure that:
1. the embedToken generated is with the correct reportObjectId & type ('report')
2. The report structure (as it is retrieved via fiddler on /modelsAndExploration call) contains resourcePackages that contain the images blob url.
3. If this is a result of a cloned report, make sure to perform DEEP CLONING and not only to clone shallow references, as the images will not be copied into the new workspace